# Setup wxWidgets on Code::Blocks

Tags: windows, setup, widgets, code-blocks

I want to setup [wxWidgets 3.2.1](https://wxwidgets.org/downloads) in [Code::Blocks 20.03](https://codeblocks.org), but with no success.

Here are the steps I took so far:

1. Installed [GCC 12.2.0](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases) MinGW-W64
2. Installed [Code::Blocks 20.03](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries/) mingw setup
3. Installed [wxWidgets 3.2.1](https://wxwidgets.org/downloads) using the Windows Installer
4. Created a wxWidgets project in Code::Blocks: `File` > `New` > `Project` > `wxWidgets Project`
5. Selected `wxWidgets 3.1.x` (since there is no entry for `wxWidgets 3.2.x`)
6. Selected project and author information, "Preferred GUI Builder" and "Application Type"
7. In the wxWidgets' location I enterd `C:\wxWidgets-3.2.1` (where it's currently installed)
8. Checked both `Create "Debug" configuration` and `Create "Release" configuration`
9. Checked all the checkboxes in "wxWidgets Library Settings":

   - `Use wxWidgets DLL`
   - `wxWidgets is built as a monolithic library`
   - `Enable unicode`

When I proceed, I get the following two warnings:

> A matching Debug configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory you specified.
> This means that Debug targets of your project will not be built.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue with these settings?

> A matching Release configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory you specified.
> This means that Release targets of your project will not be built.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue with these settings?

If I continue and try to compile my project, I get 3 of the following error:

> C:\wxWidgets-3.2.1\include\wx\platform.h 159 fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory

I headed to `C:\wxWidgets-3.2.1\include\wx` and found that `setup.h` is missing: it's actually located in `C:\wxWidgets-3.2.1\include\wx\msw` (one folder deeper).

Any ideas on how to correctly setup wxWidgets to work with Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using the [Windows Installer](https://wxwidgets.org/downloads/) only installed the source code. I had to build it myself:

```bash
cd /D C:\wxWidgets-3.2.1\build\msw
```

And then

```bash
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport 2>log.txt
```

After that, I followed the same steps above starting from step 4. The project is created without problems.

Next, since there's no entry for wxWidgets 3.2.x in Code::BLocks 20.03 (step 5 above), I had to change `libwxmsw31u.a` to `libwxmsw32u.a` under:

- `Project` > `Build options` > `Debug` > `Linker settings`
- `Project` > `Build options` > `Release` > `Linker settings`

Compiled and run the project, and it did work.

[Setting up wxWidgets with Code::Blocks in Windows](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef) was of great help.